# Implement and Test the in-app install with SKStoreProductViewController

Tags: ios, iphone

I'm using SKStoreProductViewController to display the App Store view of a selected app. 
When clicking on "install", the progress bar is displayed inside the button but the app is not installed. I know that I don't really connect to the Itunes store instead it's the special sandbox store environment. 
I have 2 questions regarding this implementation:

1. I read the Apple documentation but it's not very clear how I can test the install process on development and if I have to add specific settings on iTunes Connect to make it work. I don't do in-app purchase, I just want the users to be able to download/update/open an app. **How can I test this download process before submitting the app?**
2. Twitter App is displaying the appstore page within its app and alert the users as soon as the app has been successfully installed. **How do they know about the app's download completion**? I've seen anything in the Apple documentation that would enable this control.

Answer (score 1):

Implementing the Delegate Method :

You just need to implement the delegate method that will be called when the user has either completed or cancelled the product purchase.

Since the Your View Controller class was designated as the delegate for the SKStoreProductViewController instance, the method needs to be implemented in the Your View Controller.m file:

```
- (void)productViewControllerDidFinish:(SKStoreProductViewController *)viewController
{
    [viewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Yes, it is what I did and its works out well. However, my concern is about the "install" process which does not work right now on my build. I want to make sure that it's going to work when the app will be release don the App Store.

Comment: Yes It will work properly. I have already upload one app with this feature and it is working as expected. It will back to our app screen after downloaded the app using productViewControllerDidFinish delegate.